Retrieving Token and Cost Information for OpenAI's Whisper and Text-to-Speech (TTS) Models in Langsmith?
Is it possible to retrieve token and cost information for OpenAI's Audio and TTS models in LangSmith runs while tracing?
OpenAI Audio Models
I am able to retrieve this information for chat completion models like GPT-4 and GPT-3.5 Turbo.
Tokens and cost showing for ChatCompletion models
However, for the Audio and TTS models, only traces are being logged without any specific details.
Tokens and cost not calculated for Audio and TTS models

You should try asking in the langsmith repo

@InsertCheesyLine have already asked it there before posting the question here.
discussion forum
